# how to remove all lines which its passwords that doesnt follow password policy using regular expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Passwords are after ":" And password policy is that the password must be 7 to 32 characters long and The password must contain a mix of letters, numbers, and/or special characters also passwords containing only letters or only numbers are not accepted

Means if we have

```
username:Password42
Username52@:sssdt3
user:Pass!626795
use:uss
```

it removes all and only leaves

```
username:Password42
user:Pass!626795
```

i tried using

```
^:*(?!(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])).*$\R*
```

but it didnt work good, Idk what's wrong in it, Maybe please anyone fix it for me for my policy?

Comment: [Your previous question was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847389/how-to-remove-all-lines-which-its-passwords-that-doesnt-follow-password-policy/63847553#63847553), and I don't see any changes made here.  What have you tried already?  What isn't working about your current regex pattern?

Comment: i tried but i keep failing

Comment: i want to learn, can you please type it and tell me how did u do

Comment: No, I can't, because I actually gave a correct working answer to your previous question, and then you changed the requirements after the fact.

Comment: yes i was learning from it then you removed the comment, please if possible that tell me how to add capital letters to it or just send old one and i will try to add it myself

Comment: help me anyone please

Comment: @GlalDehk: the rule of this site is that you must show the regex you tried, before we answer. Otherwise, it is like we do your homework for you, and you learn nothing. Please edit the question and show us what regex you tried, and why it is not good.

Comment: i tried editing it, Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression to *remove* lines with wrong passwords: `^.+?:(.{1,6}|.{33,}|[[:alpha:]]+|\d+)$`:

- too short,
- too long,
- consisting of letters only,
- consisting of digits only.